# is css :not attribute able to target only one element?

Tags: css

here's the html

```
<div class="first" style="height:468px">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<div class="notme">

    <div></div>
    <div></div>

</div>
```

and the css

```
.first {background:pink}

.first div:not(.notme) {height:100%}
```

what i need to do is having all the divs inside .first to have a set height of 100% EXCEPT div.notme and all of his children.

is this possible? i tried this but it doesn't work:

```
.first div:not(div.notme, .notme div) {height:100%}
```

thanks a lot! http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/E7YAp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the syntax only [one is argument is possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot),

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument.

Comment: shame.. i had hoped that `:not([name='foo'][name='bar'])` would have been possible

Answer (score 4):

Simply overwrite the rule later on:

```
.first {background:pink}

.first > div {height:100%}
.first > div.notme, .first > div.notme > div {height: auto;}
```

The last line is more specific than the one before, so it will automatically overwrite it.